# Flask - APIs made via Flask-restful vs Class Based Views APIs

Tags: python, rest, swagger, flask-restful

From the past 1 year or so, I was building APIs using Flask Class Based views. While documenting my APIs using Swagger (earlier used along with Django), I got to know about Flask-Restful. I went through its documentation, I found out it does the same thing which I was doing from past 1 year or so. Is there anything special that I'm missing about Flask-Restful or is it just the same?

Also, how can I document Class-based views using Swagger?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at https://github.com/zalando/connexion.  This gives a swagger-first way to build out your app.  Similar to `swagger-node` and `swagger-inflector` in the https://github.com/swagger-api repository

Comment: What about the difference b/w the APIs made via Flask-restful vs Class Based Views APIs??

Comment: connexion takes advantage of the flask restful routing logic and automatically wires them.  It is a cleaner integration where the spec is the source of truth.